# Presto - Regular Expression for extracting ID from url

Tags: regex, hive, presto

I have some URLs for which i need to parse out an ID parameter.

In Presto i used `url_extract_path` to narrow down the search space, so now i have strings like this:

```
1. /LIVERPOOL-HOTELS-THE-LINER-HOTEL.H1858765.HOTEL-INFORMATION
2. /AVON-GORGE-HOTEL.H444059.HOTEL-INFORMATION
3. /NORTH-YORKSHIRE-HOTELS-ST-HILDAS-BOUTIQUE.H7265545.HOTEL-INFORMATION
```

I want to extract the number after the `.H` so for example `1858765` for #1.

Could someone suggest a regular expression for this in preso?

Answer (score 2):

Use `'\\.H([0-9]+)'` pattern, this mean literally '.H' and one or more digits, extract capturing group 1 (in parentheses) :

```
hive> select regexp_extract('/LIVERPOOL-HOTELS-THE-LINER-HOTEL.H1858765.HOTEL-INFORMATION','\\.H([0-9]+)',1);
OK
_c0
1858765
Time taken: 0.152 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select regexp_extract('/AVON-GORGE-HOTEL.H444059.HOTEL-INFORMATION','\\.H([0-9]+)',1);
OK
_c0
444059
Time taken: 0.094 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select regexp_extract('/NORTH-YORKSHIRE-HOTELS-ST-HILDAS-BOUTIQUE.H7265545.HOTEL-INFORMATION','\\.H([0-9]+)',1);
OK
_c0
7265545
Time taken: 0.056 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

You need to shield dot character for **Presto** with single back-slash `'\.H(\d+)'`:

```
select regexp_extract('LIVERPOOL-HOTELS-THE-LINER-HOTEL.H1858765.HOTEL-INFORMATION','\.H(\d+)',1);
```

Result:

```
1858765
```

Also you can use `\d+` instead of `[0-9]+` both in Hive and Presto